# What is Nakagawa repeatability measure quantifying?

Tags: r, regression, glmm, repeatability

I have been reading about repeatability estimation, and ICC and I am a little confused about how the quantity is being reported given its computation.

From [Stoffel et al 2017](https://rptR:%20repeatability%20estimation%20and%20variance%20decomposition%20by%20generalized%20linear%20mixed-effects%20models), repeatability, $R$, is computed as

$R = \frac{V_G}{V_G + V_R}$, where $V_G$ is the among-group variance and $V_G$ is the within-group (residual) variance. Let's say that the grouping level here is the individual.

The equation for $R$ is then giving the proportion of variance explained among the groups. However, I am not seeing how this represents repeatability. Furthermore, the authors [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7820162/) state that

> Repeatability is estimated from repeated measurements taken on several
> individuals and is typically calculated as the intraclass correlation
> coefficient—that is, the proportion of total variance that is
> attributable to individual identity.

How do you "get proportion of total variance that is attributable to individual identity" from the definition of $R$, which seems to be focused on among group variance? I see they said that

> Repeatability was calculated for each trait as the variance among
> individual trait means (individual‐level variance $V_G$) over the sum of
> individual‐level and residual variance

But am I missing something in thinking that $V_G$ is the difference between say individual 1 and individual 2, and not individual 1 over time 1 to N?

Also, what is the meaning of a value for $R$? If I have a value for $R$ of 0.4, what is the meaning of that in terms of repeatability?

Comment: $R$ is not "focused" on either variance: you could just as well use the equivalent statistic $1-R = V_R/(V_G+V_R)$ which now looks "focused" on $V_R.$ The *appearance* of a formula for a statistic is not what matters.  Evidently, as $V_R$ decreases, $R$ approaches $1$ from below: thus, high values of $R$ reflect relatively small residual variance -- and that's the variance that measures how much repeated measurements (within any group) are likely to vary. BTW, the typos in your descriptions make it difficult to follow your question and that might be a source of some confusion.